# how to start collector as an agent (using opentelemtry-java-instrumentation)

Tags: open-telemetry

I'm trying to instrument a sample application with opentelemtry-java-instrumentation agent (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation). By default the instrumented agent send the metrics to localhost:4317 by default (assuming there is a collector running on that port).

Seems like one of the way to run the collector is on the localhost as an agent along with the application. However, I'm unable to find any documentation on how to start the collector as an agent along with the application on a mac. Should I be building the collector locally? Any guidance. Thanks

Some documentation that were relevant were - https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/getting-started/.

Comment: Did you try this https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/getting-started/#docker?

Comment: Yup, I was wondering if we can run the collector outside of the container? Wasn't able to build/compile it on mac os.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can download the package form this repository and run the collector.
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-releases/releases